# Sign a User certificate with CA.key :openssl

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, openssl

I've a user certificate (`certname.pem`) and user key (`keyname.pem`) which I've generated using the command below.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout keyname.pem -x509 -days 365 -out certname.pem
```

Also I've generated a CA key (`ca.key.pem`) and CA root certificate (`ca.root.pem`) using the command below.

```
openssl req -x509 -days 557 -newkey rsa:1024 -out ca.root.pem -keyout ca.key.pem
```

Now I want to sign the user certificate (`certname.pem`) with the CA key (`ca.key.pem`) but I am unable to do so using the command below.

```
openssl ca -create_serial -config openssl.cnf -cert ca.root.pem -keyfile ca.key.pem -in certname.pem  -out new-certname.pem
```

as this command gives error:

```
Error reading certificate request in certname.pem
139992806578040:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:708:Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST
```

Where as the contents of my certname.pem are as follows:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

How to sign this certificate with the ca.key.pem?
Please help.

Reference for generating certificates - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWHYP_4.0.0/com.ibm.apimgmt.cmc.doc/task_apionprem_gernerate_self_signed_openSSL.html

Comment: A certificate is already signed. What a CA instead needs as input for signing is a certificate request and the error message clearly says so: *"Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST"*. Only you gave a certificate and not a certificate request.

Answer (score 2):

You included `-x509` on your original request, which in this case instructed openssl to generate a self-signed certificate named `certname.pem`.  It is a certificate, but probably not the kind you want here.

I assume you instead want to use your newly minted CA to sign your public key and create a server certificate.  You'll need to first generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR); since you have already generated the key (the one in keyname.pem) you can do this with:

```
openssl req -out keyname.csr -key keyname.pem -new
```

You can then pass this CSR to generate a certificate (as you tried):

```
openssl ca -create_serial -config openssl.cnf -cert ca.root.pem -keyfile ca.key.pem -in keyname.csr -out new-certname.pem
```

Comment: Thanks that worked :)  Unable to upvote the answer due to low reputation :(

Comment: Nearly right but see edit; re-edit or revert if you disagree.